# Sql server 2012 join query Problem. I want to join two tables and i want get first table full data and second table full data

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to get all user data and user log details. When user is absent there is no log details in log table. and i want to get the first and last punch time of the user in per day but in this query we will use in between date.
when i run the first and last time query separately i got  the first log in the first date and last log of last date
please help me to get the correct query to find correct values:

```
SELECT FORMAT(dateadd(SECOND,MIN(nDateTime), '19700101'), 'hh:mm:ss') as ftime,
       FORMAT(dateadd(SECOND,MAX(nDateTime), '19700101'), 'hh:mm:ss') as ltime 
from BioStar.dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG 
where nUserID =10000 
and FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND,nDateTime, '19700101'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') between '2019-08-20' and '2019-08-21' 
and nEventIdn=55
```

when I use the above query, it return the first log of user in 20th and last log of user in 21st.
 but I want the first and last log of 20th in one row and first and last log of  user in 21st in second row

```
SELECT a.sUserID,
       a.sUserName,
       FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, b.nDateTime, '19700101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy') as date,
       FORMAT(dateadd(SECOND,MIN(b.nDateTime), '19700101'), 'hh:mm:ss') as ftime,
       FORMAT(dateadd(SECOND,MAX(b.nDateTime), '19700101'), 'hh:mm:ss') as ltime 
from BioStar.dbo.TB_USER a 
INNER JOIN BioStar.dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG b 
    on (a.sUserID = b.nUserID) 
where FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND,b.nDateTime, '19700101'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') between '2019-08-20' and '2019-08-21' 
and b.nEventIdn=55 
group by a.sUserID
```

when run this query the below error is shown:

> Column 'BioStar.dbo.TB_USER.sUserName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the join and everything to do with the `group by`. You need to add `sUserName` to the `group by` clause, and figure out what to do with the `date` part since it also must be either in the `group by` clause or in an aggregating function (such as `min`, `max` etc'). Also, your usage of `format` slows down the query - you better use `convert` instead, but worst, the fact that you need to add seconds to January 1st 1970 to compute the date means that the `nDateTime` is stored in the wrong format. `DateTime` values in SQL Server should be stored as `DateTime2`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled convert is not working for my datetime format. it is a integer format like this '1566379619'

Comment: No, but convert will work on the result of `dateadd(SECOND,MIN(nDateTime), '19700101')`. Also, as I wrote in the last section of my previous comment, an int is not a datetime format.